# Togglz JDBCStateRepository automatically creating malformed tables in DB2

Tags: java, jdbc, togglz

I am configuring a togglz JDBCStateRepository for the first time in our company.

On the first project I converted from InMemoryStateRepository to JDBCStateRepository the project mix was:

- spring boot project
- oracle database
- already existing schema and new table specified for "table name"

I utilized

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
  <artifactId>togglz-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
    <artifactId>togglz-console</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Everything worked correctly automatically.

On the second project I converted the InMemoryStateRepository to JDBCStateRepository and the project mix was:

- plain spring project (not spring boot)
- DB2 database
- new schema and new table specified for "table name"

I utilized

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
    <artifactId>togglz-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1.Final</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
    <artifactId>togglz-console</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and upon hitting the togglz index page I get the following exception:

```
[6/7/17 10:25:55:672 EDT] 000000c4 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [TogglzConsoleServlet] in application [pp_dial2_issuance_pub]. Exception created : [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to migrate the database schema
    at org.togglz.core.repository.jdbc.JDBCStateRepository.migrateSchema(JDBCStateRepository.java:184)
    at org.togglz.core.repository.jdbc.JDBCStateRepository.<init>(JDBCStateRepository.java:152)
    at org.togglz.core.repository.jdbc.JDBCStateRepository.<init>(JDBCStateRepository.java:96)
    at com.lmig.ci.policy.publisher.issuance.togglz.ToggleFMP.getFeatureManager(ToggleFMP.java:41)
    at org.togglz.core.context.FeatureContext.findFeatureManagerInClassLoader(FeatureContext.java:108)
    at org.togglz.core.context.FeatureContext.getFeatureManagerOrNull(FeatureContext.java:74)
    at org.togglz.core.context.FeatureContext.getFeatureManager(FeatureContext.java:47)
    at org.togglz.core.manager.LazyResolvingFeatureManager.getDelegate(LazyResolvingFeatureManager.java:24)
    at org.togglz.core.manager.LazyResolvingFeatureManager.getCurrentFeatureUser(LazyResolvingFeatureManager.java:49)
    at org.togglz.console.TogglzConsoleServlet.isFeatureAdmin(TogglzConsoleServlet.java:75)
    at org.togglz.console.TogglzConsoleServlet.service(TogglzConsoleServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.togglz.servlet.TogglzFilter.doFilter(TogglzFilter.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1007)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture$1.run(AsyncChannelFuture.java:205)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.fn: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-542, SQLSTATE=42831, SQLERRMC=FEATURE_NAME, DRIVER=4.1.85
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.yc.a(yc.java:592)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.yc.a(yc.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.yc.a(yc.java:127)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.il.c(il.java:1914)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.il.d(il.java:1902)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.il.b(il.java:1369)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.h(db.java:219)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.b(db.java:45)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.t.b(t.java:38)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.sb.g(sb.java:120)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.il.P(il.java:1364)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.il.a(il.java:2261)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.il.c(il.java:614)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.il.executeUpdate(il.java:598)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcStatement.pmiExecuteUpdate(WSJdbcStatement.java:1804)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcStatement.executeUpdate(WSJdbcStatement.java:1135)
    at org.togglz.core.repository.jdbc.SchemaUpdater.execute(SchemaUpdater.java:135)
    at org.togglz.core.repository.jdbc.SchemaUpdater.migrateToVersion1(SchemaUpdater.java:39)
    at org.togglz.core.repository.jdbc.JDBCStateRepository.migrateSchema(JDBCStateRepository.java:170)
    ... 37 more
```

With the important part being:

> Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.fn: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-542,
>   SQLSTATE=42831, SQLERRMC=FEATURE_NAME, DRIVER=4.1.85

The definition of this SQLCODE and SQLSTATE can be found here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n542.html

In which it states:

> -542   column-name CANNOT BE A COLUMN OF A HASH KEY, PRIMARY KEY, A UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, OR A PARENT KEY BECAUSE IT CAN CONTAIN NULL VALUES

In other words it appears togglz is trying to create a table in which the column name "FEATURE_NAME" is both nullable and has a primary key or unique constraint on. When I reference the table created in my first project, the column "FEATURE_NAME" is non nullable and marked as a primary key. The only differences in the second project is the togglz-core vs togglz-spring-boot-starter and oracle vs db2.

Has anyone encountered this? Are there ways around this?

Answer (score 1):

The author of Togglz here.

This clearly looks like a bug. So why don't you open an issue in the Togglz issue tracker for that? You can find it [here](https://github.com/togglz/togglz/issues). Of cause a pull request to fix this would be welcome too.

However, in the meantime you could simply disable the automatic schema migration feature and create the table yourself. There is [an option](https://github.com/togglz/togglz/blob/d2532333a173ce1dd9526c03f58fd5837a4b588d/core/src/main/java/org/togglz/core/repository/jdbc/JDBCStateRepository.java#L396-L405) in the builder to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and for creating a great library!). I will submit an issue tracker and then I think what i'll do in the spirit of both solving my problem and improving Togglz is extend the existing JDBCStateRepository but overriding the appropriate functions with some modified DDL that specify non nullable on the columns. I can test it out and if it works out I can put the code changes into the issue tracker and maybe you can commit? If that doesn't work out i'll manually create it but want to try to improve Togglz along the way if easily possible. Cheers and thanks for your time.